# How to check if a class/object is loaded in php?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php  
    define('ga_email', 'xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com');    // GA Email
    define('ga_password', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');         // 2-part authorization password
    define('profile_id', 'xxxxxxxxx');            // Analytics profile ID
    $gapi_url = 'gapi/gapi.class.php';
    require_once $gapi_url;
    $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

    // here goes next code

?>
```

and it's ok. Gapi will load.

However, if I change ga_password from xxxxxxxxxxx to yyyyyyyyyyy (so the information for logging into GA are incorrect) I get a nasty error, that gapi is not loaded etc.

I need some if condition to implement so it checks if my object $ga was created or not and execte a code only then.

e.g.:

```
 <?php  
        define('ga_email', 'xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com');    // GA Email
        define('ga_password', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy');      // 2-part authorization password
        define('profile_id', 'xxxxxxxxx');            // Analytics profile ID
        $gapi_url = 'gapi/gapi.class.php';
        require_once $gapi_url;
        $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

        if($ga  loaded) {
           // SUCCESS
           // here goes next code
        } else {
           // FAILURE
           echo "Your connection details are wrong.";
        }

 ?>
```

So, instead a bad looking PHP error I will get a nicer "Your connection details are wrong."message.

Comment: presumably you get SOME kind of object back. check the object's docs to see if there's a `->error()` method, or maybe it throws an exception, etc...

Comment: "Nasty" isn't a valid PHP error. What kind of error are you getting? Is it an Exception? You can use it to your favor if it is

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: "Request failed, fopen provides no further information"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source of the class, it appears that the constructor will not throw an exception when the error details are wrong, but only when the credentials are used. Wrapping all your calls to the object in a `try...catch` block will give you some error handling capabilities:

```
try {
    $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
    // here goes next code
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // FAILURE
    echo "Your connection details are wrong.";
    // $ex->getMessage() has a detailed message
}
```

You also need to ensure you know the correct signature of the constructor method, which [appears to be the following](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/source/browse/trunk/gapi.class.php#51):

```
public function __construct($auth_method)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. It works great ;)

Answer (score 0):

On your `__construct()` of gapi check if the username and password is valid. Also create another public function or variable to return whether it is a valid login or not.

Comment: Oh, you should just be able to say `if($ga) { //is good } else { //is bad }` if you are getting an error saying it is undefined.